# Only on page refresh: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, dojo

I know this has been already asked several times but I am facing this issue only when I refresh the page several times on IE8. Chrome and FF work great. If I click on the address bar and then hit enter, the page loads fine.

The only problem is when I hit refresh a couple of times.

Any clue on how to debug this? I've tried the developer tools app with IE8 but it always says this error thats on line 0 which is not very helpful.

I must say I am using a web content management solution to create dinamic menus, and lists, which makes this more difficult to debug.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some more information? This doesn't even allude to Dojo and what part of it's code you're using at all.

Comment: Well, I know its been a while but I must say it was a statistic script that was messing with the page. I moved it to the head tag and that solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I posted on the comments, it wasn't my code but the statistic code by Nielsen that was messing with the JS.

I removed it and it worked. Then I ended up moving it to the head tag and it worked.